# RTK query unable to cancel request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-redux, rtk-query

Such a problem. i need to skip the request when there is no user.
i tried doing this and that

```js
const { data: carts = [] as ICart[], isFetching } =
 api.useGetCartProductsQuery(user.id, { skip: !user})

const { data: carts = [] as ICart[], isFetching } =
 api.useGetCartProductsQuery(user.id, { skip: true })
```

but every time I get an error

```
Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')

Source
src\app\dashboard\Dashboard.tsx (35:35) @ id

  33 | 
  34 |  const { isLoading, data: carts = [] as ICart[] } =
> 35 |      api.useGetCartProductsQuery(user.id, { skip: true })
```

Tell me how to make it work correctly.

I tried doing this and that

```
const { data: carts = [] as ICart[], isFetching } =
 api.useGetCartProductsQuery(user.id, { skip: !user})

const { data: carts = [] as ICart[], isFetching } =
 api.useGetCartProductsQuery(user.id, { skip: true })
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the same time still trying to access `user.id` - this is JavaScript code that is executed outside of RTK Query, which you have written:

```
api.useGetCartProductsQuery(user.id, { skip: !user })
```

You could try to get around that by providing some kind or default:

```
api.useGetCartProductsQuery(user ? user.id : undefined, { skip: !user })
```

but that is kinda unsatisfying to read.

Instead you can use the `skipToken` (exported from RTK Query)

```
api.useGetCartProductsQuery(user ? user.id : skipToken)
```